# How to enforce a min-width for a page (css)

Tags: html, css

I've got a site designed for desktop and tablet, and it looks good on tablet.

Mobile wasn't entirely neglected (bootstrap was used, so it is at least bearable) but that wasn't the focus.

Needless to say, some pages don't look that great on mobile. Rather than restructure it all, when virtually nobody will ever access this on a mobile, I'd rather just put a min-width on the page and accept when the occasional mobile user browses to it they'll have a horizontal scroll bar.

What CSS do I need to enforce a minimum width (of about 450px) for an entire page?

Thanks

Comment: add class .container or .container-fluid to body and let bootstrap handle it.

Comment: `min-width` perhaps?

Comment: read and try  this , http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know the structure of your CSS and HTML, but did you tried

```
html,body
{
   min-width: 700px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried with `body` before and it didn't work - but with `html` too it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `min-width` to the `body`:

```
body {
   min-width: 450px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/88mut78t/

Answer (score 0):

wrap the entire page in a div and give it an id of "container" etc.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="container">

everything else

</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#container
{
min-width: 450px; 
}
```

as long as the page is responsive, the container shouldn't change a thing other than not letting the width fall below 450px